# PhantomJS onLoadFinished not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1 to take mobile screenshots but some of them don't come out right because page isn't fully rendered.  I have tried to use the onLoadFinished event but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(args[1]);

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {

    page.viewportSize = { width: 414, height: 736 };

    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 414, height: 736 };
    page.render(args[2]);
    console.log(args[2]);
    phantom.exit();

});
```

It just hangs and doesn't return.  I got around this by using a 2 second hard coded delay but this isn't good as I don't know every site will load in 2 seconds.

This is hard coded delay Im using:

```
page.open(args[1], function () {

    page.viewportSize = { width: 414, height: 736 };

    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 414, height: 736 };

    setTimeout(function () {
        page.render(args[2]);
        console.log(args[2]);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);

});
```

How do I get the code working with the proper load event?

Comment: Are there any errors? Use [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official PhantomJS `rasterize.js` script used for taking screenshots of pages [uses a 200ms timeout](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/b5e44097413cebe584e84f979b265118cde77a12/examples/rasterize.js#L43):

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

(copied from source linked above)

It's OK and recommended to do the same instead of rendering directly inside the event.

Comment: This doesn't use the load event.  It is similar approach to my workaround I posted above.  I would prefer to use the load event instead of hardcoded delay http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html .  A timeout is sensible but I cant get the load event to work so it would timeout 100% of the time.

Comment: That's not correct; It does use the `onLoadFinished` event. The callback passed to `page.open()` is [equivalent to using `onLoadFinished` manually](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html): `Once the page is loaded, the optional callback is called using page.onLoadFinished`. Keep in mind that the script I linked to is an official PhantomJS script used for taking screenshots of pages. Using a timeout is recommended by the PhantomJS team itself.

Comment: Ahh OK, I understand now, thanks for explaining. There must be another reason why some sites need a longer timeout then.

Comment: @Guerrilla Pages like that usually have JS that continues to run after the page is technically loaded. There's no way for PhantomJS (or any browser) to detect this and delay the `onLoadFinished` event, so manually tweaking the timeout becomes necessary.